# Grant server and database role permissions to an application role?

Tags: sql-server

I have following situation: my user connects to SQL Server as a user with no privileges and then he authorises to application role. Is it possible to configure application role to allow him adding MSSQL login and database user when he is already authenticated?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer seems to be no for the logins, at least without setting a trace flag. According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190998%28v=sql.100%29.aspx):

> In SQL Server, application roles cannot access server-level metadata
>   because they are not associated with a server-level principal. To
>   disable this restriction and thereby allow application roles to access
>   server-level metadata, set the global flag 4616

I'm not sure why you want to use an application role here anyway: if you trust people enough to let them manage SQL Server security then you might as well just give them `securityadmin` permissions directly.

It's common practice for trusted administrators to have two Windows or SQL Server logins, e.g. `SomeUser` and `SomeUserAdmin`. Only the admin account has permissions to manage security, so they can do most of their work with a normal account without special privileges, and use their admin account only when necessary.